# Why don't these tkinter programs behave identically?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I have 2 codes I made. The 2nd one is based off of the first one. Unfortunately for some reason the 2nd one doesn't work even though the first one does.

First code:

```
import time
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
t=StringVar()
num=1
t.set(str(num)
thelabel = Label(root, textvariable=t).pack()

def printnum (x):
    while x<= 100:
        t.set(str(x))
        x += 1
        root.update()
        time.sleep(30)

printnum(num)
root.mainloop()
```

This code works like a charm. Here is the other one.

Second code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

import Adafruit_DHT as dht
import time
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
k=StringVar()
num = 1
k.set(str(num))
thelabel = Label(root, textvariable=k).pack
def printnum(x):
    while x <= 10000000000000:
       h,t = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22, 4)
       newtext = "Temp%s*C Humidity=%s" %(t,h)
       k.set(newtext)
       x += 1
       root.update
       time.sleep(30)

printnum(num)
root.mainloop()
```

The code runs but it doesn't do anything, no window pops up like the other code does. Please help I cannot figure out how to fix this. Or why the first one works and the second one doesn't.

Comment: `float object`... `t` is a float, not a stringvar, because you re-used `t` in `d,t=dht...` and trashed the stringvar it used to be.

Comment: The first code is missing the last parentheses on `t.set(str(num)`

Comment: `t=StringVar()` but `newtext` is float

Comment: try `str(newtext)`

Comment: just like you've done above: `t.set(str(num)`

Comment: The indenting is wrong in the while loop in the first code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root.update` doesn't do anything.  You need to add `()`:

```
root.update()
```

That being said, your algorithm is the wrong way to run periodic tasks in tkinter. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37681471/7432

Answer (score 3):

You're overwriting the previous value of t with the temperature from read_retry on this line:

```
h,t = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22, 4)
```

Then, when you try to call `set`, `t` is now a float, so doesn't have a set method. Use a different variable name instead of `t` for one of them.

Comment: I fixed the overwriting error, it still doesn't work. I edited it back into my question.

Comment: See @BryanOakley 's reponse, I believe it's correctly identified the next part of your error.